# How is this not a run-on sentence?

Tags: punctuation

> Although short sentences tend to be dismissed as amateur or juvenile, there are times when short sentences work well, *when a work can even demand such a style.*

I come across sentences like this often and I'm not sure how the italicized bit above is added to the sentence. Isn't it a run-on sentence?

Comment: *when a work can demand such a style* is **not** an independent clause.

Comment: I would recast sentence.  For example, "Although short sentences in a work [I added "in a work"] tend to be dismissed as amateur . . ., there are times when short sentences work well and, moreover, when a work can even demand such a style."  Also, depending on context, the phrase "and when a work can even demand such a style" could be in parentheses or even preceded by a dash if you were to leave out the "moreover" [i.e., ". . . there are times when short sentences work well (and when a work can even demand such a style)]. Or, ". . . work well--and when a work can even demand such a style."

Answer (score 4):

Run-on sentences have to do with more than one independent clause. Your sentence has only one: *There are times.* The "when..." parts are adverbial clauses in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the sentence above is trying to say, "there a times when short sentences work well," and there are times "when a work can even demand such a style. Maybe this isn't what was meant but I would add the italicized part like this:

"Although... juvenile, there are times when short sentences work well and when a work can even demand such a style."
(without a comma because *when a work can demand such a style* is a dependent clause)

Comment: No, the same set of times is described, only, divided into two clauses. In that single set, "short sentences work well" every single time, though not every single time might "such a style" actually be "demanded" by some agent other than the author's own stylistic moxie.

Comment: The ", when" replaces _, at which times_. You seem to think that the comma replaces _and times_, but it simply replaces _and_.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, one can think a sentence is run-on because of its style or because of its grammar (or both).  But even with grammar alone it's hard to define the problem.  Consider the famous first sentence (and paragraph) of A Tale of Two Cities:

*It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way – in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.*

On the 'one independent clause per sentence' theory, this is going to be a massive run-on sentence, and a grammatical error.

On the opposite end, you might bite the bullet and just say that it's about stylistic preference or norms.  Certainly the Dickensian sentence structure above would be inappropriate in a technical bulletin or in a newspaper article.

My inclination is to endorse both theories selectively.  Some sentences are 'run on' just because they are too long and unclear for the contexts in which they occur; others are 'run on' because the semantic connection between two clauses is so tenuous that it is simply normatively incorrect to put them in the same sentence.  Whether that second intuition can be precisely specified is an open question (to me at least).